# Table Valued Functions vs Inline SQL Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was of the opinion that functions are always slower than inline queries in Stored Procedures. This is because functions are not pre-compiled, so the extra overhead of compiling the function is reduced.

But the following proves it wrong.

I created a multi-line table valued function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_SplitString] 
(
    @TheString NVARCHAR(255), 
    @Delimiter CHAR(1) = ' '
)
RETURNS @Ret TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, Value NVARCHAR(255))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @X XML = (SELECT CONVERT(XML, ' <root> <s>' + REPLACE(@TheString, @Delimiter, '</s> <s>') + '</s>   </root> '))

    INSERT INTO @Ret (Value)
    SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(20)')
    FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c)   
    RETURN 
END
```

Then, created a Stored Procedure that has a call to this function, as well as the same SQL statements that are in this function

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Split CHAR(1) = ' '
    DECLARE @X XML
    DECLARE @TestString VARCHAR(255) = 'Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text'

    -- using a TVF
    SELECT Value FROM dbo.UDF_SplitString(@TestString, @Split)

    -- without TVF
    SELECT @X = CONVERT(XML, ' <root> <s>' + REPLACE(@TestString, @Split, '</s> <s>') + '</s>   </root> ')
    SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(20)') FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c)
END
```

Now when I see the `Estimated Execution Plan`, it shows 50% - 50% (which is what I expected anyways).

But when I see the `Actual Execution Plan`, table valued function is clearly the winner. I tried to time the individual queries and it confirms the same. I also changed the order of queries and tried with shorter and longer strings, but still the same results.

[image: tvf-vs-inline]

Does anyone know what's going on here? How is the TVF better than the equivalent inline query?

Comment: As Brent Ozar once wrote to me - [That percentage is the estimated cost, not the actual – you can’t rely on that for performance tuning.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/01/how-to-remove-times-from-dates-in-sql-server/#comment-3198631)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really think 0% and 100% are the figures you are expecting as "running faster due to pre-compilation"?

From the screen you included, it is more about the limitation of cost calculation of MSSQL. The run-time inside the TVF call is totally skipped from the analysis so you have lost the information actually.

To fairly make the experiment, I suggest you can time the execution by logging the start and end time of a procedure call, use 2 separate procedures, one calls the TVF 1000 times, one calls the non-TVF 1000 times. That should give you the more real execution time.

But back to the question, from my understanding, including a static query inside function or inside procedure should have similar outcome in terms of the pre-compilation done. So I do share the same 50%-50% expectation with you.

Comment: The starting point of all this was a stored proc which starts with these lines and has over 100 sql statements. Surprisingly 2 places where these statements were used showed as 45% each while the rest 10% distributed throughout the SP. Moving it into a TVF brings them down to 0% since the string being split is less than 10 words.

Answer (score -1):

```
--ctrl + M / actual execution plan
----------------------------------

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_SplitString_x] 
(
    @TheString NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @Delimiter CHAR(1) = ' '
)
RETURNS @Ret TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, Value NVARCHAR(255))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @X XML = (SELECT CONVERT(XML, ' <root> <s>' + REPLACE(@TheString, @Delimiter, '</s> <s>') + '</s>   </root> '))

    INSERT INTO @Ret (Value)
    SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c)   
    RETURN 
END
GO


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_SplitString_y] 
(
    @TheString NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @Delimiter CHAR(1) = ' '
)
RETURNS @Ret TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, Value NVARCHAR(255))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @X XML = (SELECT CONVERT(XML, ' <!--' + REPLACE(@TheString, @Delimiter, '--> <!--') + '-->'))

    INSERT INTO @Ret (Value)
    SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    FROM @X.nodes('comment()') T(c)   
    RETURN 
END 
GO

DECLARE @Split CHAR(1) = ' '
DECLARE @TestString nvarchar(max) = replicate(cast('Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text' as nvarchar(max)), 230)
    
declare @d datetime2;

select @d = sysdatetime()    
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[UDF_SplitString_y](@TestString, @Split)  
select datediff(ms, @d, sysdatetime()) split_y_ms;

select @d = sysdatetime()  
SELECT * FROM dbo.UDF_SplitString_x(@TestString, @Split) --same cost...
select datediff(ms, @d, sysdatetime()) as split_x_ms; -- diff execution time
GO


--caveat
SELECT * FROM dbo.UDF_SplitString_x(N'this is & a test' , ' ') --error, xml invalid chars
go
SELECT * FROM dbo.UDF_SplitString_y(N'this is & a test' , ' ') --ok
go
SELECT * FROM dbo.UDF_SplitString_y(N'this is <!-- a test' , ' ') --error, comment markup in the string
go


drop function [dbo].[UDF_SplitString_x] 
go
drop function [dbo].[UDF_SplitString_y] 
go
```